# Is there a way to write a function if row2 = row1 in snowflake like we do in excel

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have this output. I want to write this code in snowflake (if MPolicy in RowN 2 = MPolicy in RowN 1 then "2" if not "1") as we do in excel IF(A1=A2,2,1). I have upload pictures from excel of what I am trying to accomplish in snowflake.

```sql
SELECT
    Row_Number() Over (Order by Target_QUIKMSTR.MPOLICY Asc) as RowN,
    Target_QUIKMSTR.MPOLICY
FROM Target_QUIKMSTR
         LEFT JOIN Target_quikridr ON Target_QUIKMSTR.MPOLICY = Target_quikridr.MPOLICY
WHERE ((Target_QUIKMSTR.MPOLICY) Like '%N')
  AND ((Target_QUIKMSTR.MSTATUS) = '54')
  AND ("DATE"(Target_QUIKMSTR.MSTATDATE) Between '5/1/2020' And '5/31/2020')
```

**Input:**

[image]

**Expected output:**

[image]

Comment: SELECT Row_Number() Over (Order by Target_QUIKMSTR.MPOLICY Asc) as RowN, Target_QUIKMSTR.MPOLICY
FROM (Target_QUIKMSTR LEFT JOIN Target_quikridr ON Target_QUIKMSTR.MPOLICY = Target_quikridr.MPOLICY) LEFT JOIN Target_quikvalf ON Target_QUIKMSTR.MPOLICY = Target_quikvalf.MPOLICY
WHERE ((Target_QUIKMSTR.MPOLICY) Like '%N') AND ((Target_QUIKMSTR.MSTATUS)='54') AND ("DATE" (Target_QUIKMSTR.MSTATDATE) Between '5/1/2020' And '5/31/2020')

Comment: Can you show an example of the output you're expecting? What about all of the other rows? what values would you want against those?

Comment: @SimonDarr I have edited the question and uploaded some pictures. I hope this helps simplify things. I am new to this platform, and as such, don't know all my way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like the following:

```sql
with orig_table as (
    SELECT
        Row_Number() Over (Order by Target_QUIKMSTR.MPOLICY Asc) as RowN,
        Target_QUIKMSTR.MPOLICY as mpolicy
    FROM Target_QUIKMSTR
             LEFT JOIN Target_quikridr ON Target_QUIKMSTR.MPOLICY = Target_quikridr.MPOLICY
    WHERE ((Target_QUIKMSTR.MPOLICY) Like '%N')
      AND ((Target_QUIKMSTR.MSTATUS) = '54')
      AND ("DATE"(Target_QUIKMSTR.MSTATDATE) Between '5/1/2020' And '5/31/2020')
)
select
    rown,
    mpolicy,
    iff(mpolicy = lead(mpolicy) over (order by rown), 1, 2)
from orig_table
```

This SQL checks each row and the row after it (ordered by the ROWN field). If the row after it is the same then it puts a 1 in the `check_col` otherwise it puts a 2. Note that you need to make sure the rows are ordered by the `rown` field for this to work.

| ROWN | MPOLICY | CHECK_COL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 117402N | 1 |
| 2 | 117402N | 2 |
| 3 | 117409N | 1 |
| 4 | 117409N | 2 |
| 5 | 118443N | 1 |
| 6 | 118443N | 2 |

In your question I think you have your logic mixed up based on your expected results screenshot. In your question you say

> if MPolicy in RowN 1 = MPolicy in RowN 2 then "2" if not "1"

But your expected results is the other way around. My SQL is based on your screenshot of expected results.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I apologise for the confusion. I have made the correction.

Comment: Also, I did input the code but got an error. ERROR: SQL compilation error: Window function [ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TARGET_QUIKMSTR.MPOLICY ASC NULLS LAST)] may not be nested inside another window function.

Comment: Oh, I've updated my answer to incorporate your original code. I can't test it properly though because I don't have your tables in my database. Should work. You have to put your row_number in a subquery or a CTE like I've done above.

Comment: Yes, it did work. I also did that after my initial comment